# Why there isn't an output page for the first pass in external merge sort

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, sorting

I'm learning external merge sort in DBMS. The first pass in the external merge sort read in B pages at a time and provide N/B runs each, where N is the total pages need sorting and B is the buffer pages available. However, in the afterwards passes, one page in the buffer pages are needed for output. So I wonder why an output page is not needed on the first pass? My understanding is that the first pass needs to output the run, so one output page should be left for the run.

Comment: Show us your current code attempt. And add some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first pass, all B pages become output pages after they are sorted using an internal sort (multi-threading can help during this phase). The first pass repeats the pattern: read B pages, sort B pages, write B pages, resulting in N/B sorted runs on the external device. On the remaining merge passes, only one of the pages is needed to be used as an output buffer, while the remaining B-1 pages can be used for reading and merging into the single output page which is written each time it is filled by merge operations.